# Find a (finite) sum involving n-th root of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

Evaluate $1+2\omega+3\omega^2+\ldots+n\omega^{n-1}$ where $\omega\neq 1$ is an n-th root of unity.

**My solution**

Let $S=1+2\omega+3\omega^2+\ldots+n\omega^{n-1}$

$\omega S=\omega+2\omega^2+\ldots+(n-1)\omega^{n-1}+n\omega^n$

$S-\omega S=1+\omega+\omega^2+\ldots+\omega^{n-1}-n\omega^n$

But $1+\omega+\omega^2+\ldots+\omega^{n-1}=0$ and $\omega^n=1$

So, $S-\omega S=0-n$

$(1-\omega)S=-n$

$S=\dfrac{n}{\omega-1}$

I think my working is right but is it possible to simplify further to obtain the answer purely as a function of $n$? For example, would it make sense to write $\dfrac{-n}{1-\omega}$ as $-n(1+\omega+\omega^2+\ldots)$?

Comment: So, $n=2, \omega=-1$ we get $1+2(-1) = \frac{2}{1-(-1)}$  Use this to find your mistake.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the sign error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reasoning is correct (in the original post it was correct up to sign)

Writing the result as a geometric series is correct but IMO not very helpful, especially since the series does not converge.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the sign error.